# Largest number of elements that a basis for V in $R^n$could have?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V ⊆ R^n$ be a subspace of $R^n$

(a) What does it mean for a set of vectors $S$ = {$v1, . . . , vk$} in $R^n$
to be a basis for V ?

(b) What is the largest number of elements that a basis for V could have?

I know that this supposed to be an easy question but I can't seem to understand b. I know that for a, the vectors span $R^n$ and are linearly independent. But I can't seem to figure out what b is asking for. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you already read about the concept of "dimension" of a vector space? It is the cardinality (number of the elements) of any one of it's (infinitely many) bases. Every basis of the same vector space has the same cardinality.

Comment: Thanks! Copy into the answer section for correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(a):**

$S = \{ v_1, \dotsc, v_k \}$ is a basis of $V$ means that for each $x\in V$ there exists **unique** $x_1,\dotsc, x_k\in\mathbb R$ such that
$$ x = \sum_{i=1}^k x_i v_i. $$

**(b):**

[Steinitz exchange lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz_exchange_lemma) shows the every basis of a finitely spanned vector space has the same number of elements, that invariant is called *dimension*. Since $V$ is subspace of $\mathbb R^n$, we can extend a basis of $V$ to a basis of $\mathbb R^n$. Thus, we have 
$$\dim V \le \dim \mathbb R^n = n.$$